# Como definir um mesmo INNER JOIN para diferentes campos relacionados com a mesma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho um problema que é o seguinte, no [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) eu tenho uma tabela **`portaria`** que tem uma `Fk_key` com a tabela **`usuario`**, que é quem autoriza, e, uma relação N para N com a tabela **`usuario`** para quem entra pela portaria (pois, pode ser duas pessoas ao mesmo tempo) Tabela: **`usuarionportaria_solicitante`** dessa forma eu teria uma SQL com algo parecido a isto:

```
SELECT ups.usuario_usuario_id, portaria.fk_quem_registra FROM portaria
INNER JOIN usuarionportaria_solicitante as ups
ON portaria.portaria_id = ups.portaria_portaria_id
INNER JOIN usuario as usuario
ON usuario.usuario_id = ups.usuario_usuario_id
```

No meu retorno vem 2 usuários solicitantes assim como esperado dos dois registros que tem lá, porém eu quero que retorne os nomes ao invés dos `ids`, o meu empecilho é o `portaria.fk_quem_registra`, quero que retorne algo como:

```
usuarios_solicitantes   |   quem_registrou
José Carlos             |   Froslass
Willian da Silva        |   Froslass
```

Se possível, apenas com o `INNER`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, .... `JOIN` seria melhor por questão de aprendizado, sei que uma `sub-query` resolveria, espero que entendam, queria fazer essa co-relação entre cada usuário e seu `id` através do `INNER JOIN` ou de qualquer outro `JOIN`.

Comment: Presumindo que em sua tabela `usuario`exista um campo `nome_usuario`basta substituir `ups.usuario_usuario_id` por `usuario.nome_usuario`.

Comment: Na verdade ela tem apenas o id

Comment: E então de onde você poderia buscar o nome? Você só consegue recuperar de seu banco de dados os dados que lá existam.

Comment: Através da tabela usuário, lá contém a relação id / nome do usuário, só que, estou tentando fazer relacionamento com INNER JOIN pra isso, e, ao mesmo tempo que tenho 2 campos pra retornar com usuários diferentes no caso: Quem Solicita e Quem Registra, porém ambos são id's da tabela de Usuários

Comment: pode responder a minha pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/469237/identificar-registros-sequenciais-de-cada-usuário

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pela sua explicação me parece que o que deseja é:

```
SELECT solicitante.nome_usuario, autorizador.nome_usuario
FROM portaria 
INNER JOIN usuarionportaria_solicitante as ups ON portaria.portaria_id = ups.portaria_portaria_id
INNER JOIN usuario as solicitante ON solicitante.usuario_id = ups.usuario_usuario_id
INNER JOIN usuario as autorizador ON autorizador.usuario_id = ups.usuario_usuario_id;
```

isto é a tabela `usuario` participa com dois papéis: `solicitante` e `autorizador`.

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu precisava!

Comment: me ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/469237/identificar-registros-sequenciais-de-cada-usuário